# Qt5 Remote Object as interprocess communication between a Windows service and a normal process

Tags: windows-services, qt5, qtremoteobjects

I need to have a bidirectional communication channel between a Windows service and a normal process. I have tried with Qt5 Remote Object (source is on service side, replica is on the process side), but I cannot connect. Is there a way to use Qt5 RO ? What other options are available ?

regards
Bogdan

Answer (score 1):

I have found that a service and a normal process can communicate using Qt5 Remote Objects, but only when the source is a normal process and the replica is daemon. The other way around does not work.

hope this helps

Comment: Do you know if this limitation still exists in more recent versions of Qt ? Tx.